# Normal distribution property

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I need to prove a property of the normal distribution.
I have two r.v. $\alpha \sim N(\overline{\alpha}, \sigma_{\alpha}^2)$ and $\xi \sim N(\overline{\xi}, \sigma_{\xi}^2)$ and want to establish that the function $\eta=\alpha+\beta \xi$ is a normal distribution with 
$\eta \sim N(\overline{\alpha}+\beta \overline{\xi},  \sigma_{\alpha}^2+  \beta^2 \sigma_{\xi}^2 + 2\beta \sigma_{\alpha \xi})$.
Now If I can prove that $\alpha$ and $\xi$
are jointly normal then any function of both of them will be normally distributed.

Property: $\alpha$ and $\xi$ are jointly normal if
 $$\alpha=aU+bV$$
 $$\xi=cU+dV$$
where U and V are independent normal r.v. $U\sim N(\overline{u}, \sigma_U^2)$ and $V\sim N(\overline{v}, \sigma_V^2)$.
So that  $\alpha$ and $\xi$ can be expressed as linear combination of U and V. Then:
$$\alpha \sim N(\underbrace{a\overline{u} +b \overline{v}}_{\overline{\alpha}}, \underbrace{a^2\sigma_U^2+b^2\sigma_V^2}_{\sigma_{\alpha}^2})$$

$$\xi \sim N(\underbrace{c\overline{u} +d \overline{v}}_{\overline{\xi}}, \underbrace{c^2\sigma_U^2+d^2\sigma_V^2}_{ \sigma_{\xi}^2})$$
Having the next equation system:

$$a\overline{u} +b \overline{v}=\overline{\alpha}$$

$$c\overline{u} +d \overline{v}=\overline{\xi}$$

$$a^2\sigma_U^2+b^2\sigma_V^2 =\sigma_{\alpha}^2$$

$$c^2\sigma_U^2+d^2\sigma_V^2= \sigma_{\xi}^2$$

Do I need to solve this system to prove that $\alpha$ and $\xi$ are jointly normally distributed ?.
A priori the only constraint that I would have over the variables is that all variances have to be positive.

Comment: 1. If you can prove that $\alpha$ and $\xi$ are jointly Normal than any *linear* function of them will be Normally distributed.  2. Are you making the assumption that $\alpha$ and $\xi$ are jointly Normally distributed?  (Note that two variables being Normally distributed does not imply they are jointly Normally distributed, see https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MarginalNormalityDoesNotImplyBivariateNormality/#more for an example.)

Comment: You can't _prove_ that two normal random variables are _jointly_ normal without any additional information: the most common extra piece of additional information is that they _are_ indeed jointly normal, but something like _all_ linear combinations of the random variables are normally distributed will also work. That _all_ is a very important word; just $X+Y$ (which is just _one_ linear combination of $X$ and $Y$) being normally distributed) is insufficient.